# Can #define include previously defined variables?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

How are the definitions in **C** processed? Are they processed in order of line numbers?

For example, will the following statements work?

```
#define ONE  1
#define TWO  (ONE+1)
```

Could there be any problems with definitions that depend on previous definitions?

Comment: Why not just try it yourself?

Comment: You're right. I should have tried it out myself first.

Comment: you should also make it a habit of placing every argument in its own parenthesis, e.g. here: `((ONE)+1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, one `#define` can reference other `#define` substitutions and macros without any problem.

Moreover, the expression on these constants would remain a constant expression.

Your second expression would be textually equivalent to `(ONE+1)` replacement in the text, with no limits to the level of nesting. In other words, if you later define

```
#define THREE (TWO+1)
```

and then use it in an assignment `i = THREE`, you would get

```
i = ((ONE+1)+1)
```

after preprocessing.

If you are planning to use this trick with numeric values, a common alternative would be to use an `enum` with specific values, i.e.

```
enum {
    ONE = 1
,   TWO = ONE+1
,   THREE = TWO+1
,   ... // and so on
};
```

Answer (score 4):

They're processed at point when they're used, so you example and even this

```
#define TWO  (ONE+1)
#define ONE  1
```

will work.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to check by yourself:

```
g++ test.cpp 
gcc test.c
```

For strict compiler check:

```
gcc test.c -pedantic
```

And all worked for me!

test.c/test.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A 9
#define B A

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n",B);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The compiler processes the `#define`-s in the order they were de...fined. After each `#define` gets processed, the preprocessor then proceeds to process all text after this `#define`, using it in the state left by this `#define`. So, in your example:

```
#define ONE  1
#define TWO  (ONE+1)
```

It first processes `#define ONE  1`, replacing all further occurunces of `ONE` with `1`. So, the second macro becomes

```
#define TWO  (1+1)
```

That is how it will be processed and applied by the preprocessor.

The reverse example:

```
#define TWO  (ONE+1)
#define ONE  1
```

will also work. Why? Well, the preprocessor will take the first `#define`, scan the code for any occurences of `TWO`, and replace it with `(ONE+1)`. Then it reaches the second `#define`, and replaces all occurences of `ONE`, including those put in place by the previous `#define`, with 1.

I'd personally prefer the former approach over the latter: it's plainly easier for the preprocessor to handle.